# jQuery plugin for contextual menu

Tags: jquery

I need to have a fancy jQuery contextual menu for my web app; when the user clicks a point I would like to show a menu as a balloon or other graphical items with different options.

Are there any similar examples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#demo

It's also pretty easy to build from scratch...

```
$(".target").bind("contextmenu", function(){
    $("#contextMenu").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) for the popup part.  You will still need to populate and style your menu links, but [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) provides a nice browser-independent balloon-type popup.